# looping through phone fields of input type text jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a form containing 5 - 6 phone fields in the form of text fields. All these phone fields have a common class "phoneclass". So I need to iterate through all these phone fields and get the value of the individual text fields(area code, local 3 and local 4 ) once I have these values, I have to validate each of these values.
I have created a fiddle for reference. I have to only use the phoneClass for getting the value of the text fields. Without using the individual field id's I need to get the value of these 3 text fields using phoneClass and then I can put that into an array and then manipulate it.
Can anyone please help me how i can do this?

http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/79/

```
<div class="phoneclass">
<label for="owner_phone">Owner Phone:</label>
<div class="input-phone">
  <input type="text" id="owner_area_code" name="owner_area_code" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" />
  <span class="inline-text">-</span>
  <input type="text" id="owner_local3" name="owner_local3" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" />
  <span class="inline-text">-</span>
  <input  type="text" id="owner_local4" name="owner_local4" minlength="4" maxlength="4" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" />
  <span class="inline-text">Ext.</span>
  <input  type="text" id="owner_extn" name="owner_extn" maxlength="5" style="width: 40px"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="owner_phone" />
</div>
</div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="phoneclass">
    <label for="owner_phone1">Owner Phone1:</label>
<div class="input-phone">
  <input type="text" id="owner_area_code1" name="owner_area_code1" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" />
  <span class="inline-text">-</span>
  <input type="text" id="owner_local31" name="owner_local31" minlength="3" maxlength="3" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" />
  <span class="inline-text">-</span>
  <input  type="text" id="owner_local41" name="owner_local41" minlength="4" maxlength="4" title="Owner number has either been left blank or the data entered was invalid" style="width: 60px" />
  <span class="inline-text">Ext.</span>
  <input  type="text" id="owner_extn1" name="owner_extn1" maxlength="5" style="width: 40px"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="owner_phone1" />
</div>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" id="submitBtn"/>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: precise your question,very hard to understand what you need.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan..I need to iterate through the phoneClass div and get the 3 text field values..i dont want to get the values by using teh field id's. i want to use the div class and then by using children() or nth-dhild(), need to get the values of the 3 text fields..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like

1) loop through each element with class name **`phoneclass`**.

2) Within each div with class `phoneclass`, pick iterate their children using **`find()`** method.

```
 $('.phoneclass').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input').each(function (index, value) {
            console.log($(value).val());
        });
    });
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/jUQYr/82/)

Comment: Hi Praveen..I tried to put ur code in the fiddle..but something is going worng..could u please suggest..http://jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/81/

Comment: @user1049057 Glad to help you :)  I've added some content so that you can understand what the code does.

Comment: Hi Praveen one query..I need to get only input type=text..since there is a type=hidden in my div..so i can do like this right?..$(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function (index, value)

Comment: @user1049057 Yup! you can do it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42463/discussion-between-user1049057-and-praveen-jeganathan)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
for(i=0;i<$('.phoneclass').length;i++){
    phoneArray=[]; // store the values
    $('.phoneclass').eq(i).find('input:visible').each(function(index, element) {
        phoneArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    phoneObject = {}; // store the phone number
    phoneObject.areaCode = phoneArray[0];
    phoneObject.local3 = phoneArray[1];
    phoneObject.local4 = phoneArray[2];
    phoneObject.ext = phoneArray[3];
    alert("Phone"+phoneObject.areaCode+phoneObject.local3+phoneObject.local4);
    phoneNumbers.push(phoneObject); // Array of phone numbers
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/jUQYr/85/)

One more.

```
var phoneNumbers = [];
$('.phoneclass').each(function(index, element) {
    phoneArray=[]; // store the values
    $(this).find('input:visible').each(function(index, element) {
        phoneArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    phoneObject = {}; // store the phone number
    phoneObject.areaCode = phoneArray[0];
    phoneObject.local3 = phoneArray[1];
    phoneObject.local4 = phoneArray[2];
    phoneObject.ext = phoneArray[3];
    alert("Phone"+phoneObject.areaCode+phoneObject.local3+phoneObject.local4);
    phoneNumbers.push(phoneObject); // Array of phone numbers

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/jUQYr/83/)